# Change color title if category is

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want to put this if statement:

```
<?php 
if ( in_category( 'School' )) {
    echo <p class="post-title" style="color: blue;">
} elseif ( in_category( array( 'Tropical Birds', 'small-mammals' ) )) {
    echo <p class="post-title" style="color: red;">
} else {
    echo <p class="post-title" style="color: black;">
}
?>
```

Into this piece of code:

```
<?php the_title () ?>
```

So my intention is to give the post title another color when it is posted in a different category. I'm using wordpress

Comment: so you are asking for the location of the file? or if it will work? have you try it?

Comment: I am little bit confuse, what o/p function `the_title()` should return here. you want to replace your block of code with `the_title()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mess with PHP to do this. Just edit your theme's CSS file and add the following rules:

```
.category-school .post-title { color:blue !important; }

.category-tropical-birds .post-title,
.category-small-mammals .post-title { color:red !important; }
```

(You'll have to use the correct slug names for these categories (`school`, `tropical-birds`, etc.), but you can find these easily enough by visiting `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category`).

For most themes, you can probably omit the `!important` flags.

Answer (score 0):

squeamish ossifrage has given a good CSS solution.

I am a bit confused as to what you are asking, however to merge to two scripts you would simply use:

```
    <?php 
if ( in_category( 'School' )) {
    echo <p class="post-title" style="color: blue;"> the_title() </p>;
} elseif ( in_category( array( 'Tropical Birds', 'small-mammals' ) )) {
    echo <p class="post-title" style="color: red;"> the_title() </p>;
} else {
    echo <p class="post-title" style="color: black;"> the_title() </p>;
}
?>
```